# awk help > Sending output to a command

Tags: openwrt

I am by no means a programmer. I'll put that right out there. However, I'm trying to write a script that writes fstab entries after grabbing uuid data. This is in a OpenWRT environment on my router. My goal:

1. Grab uuid info using awk, like:

blkid /dev/sdb2 | awk -F'UUID="|"' '{print $2}'

2. Send the full uuid output to the end of this command:

uci set fstab.@mount[-1].uuid=

3. Execute that command with the correct uuid.

This command writes that uuid to the correct place in fstab. How can this be accomplished in a bash-script?

Thanks,

KG

Answer (score 0):

You can either execute the command from within awk (using `system(...)`), or from within the shell (using `uci set fstab.@mount[-1].uuid=$(blkid ...)`).

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it with the uci command but I believe this should do what you need.

```
bblkid /dev/sda1 | uci set fstab.@mount[-1].uuid=$( awk -F'UUID="|"' '{print $2}' )
```

Edit: this would probably be better.

```
uci set fstab.@mount[-1].uuid=$( bblkid /dev/sda1 | awk -F'UUID="|"' '{print $2}' )
```

Edit 2: little bit shorter but should get the same result. Promise this is the last one

```
uci set fstab.@mount[-1].uuid=$( bblkid /dev/sda1 | tr -d UUID=\" )
```

Answer (score 0):

The above options didn't work quite right.

What if I have this in fstab:

option uuid 'hotdog'

I want to replace the word "hotdog" with the output of the uuid from this command:

On my router that output looks like:

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# blkid /dev/sdb2 | awk -F'UUID="|"' '{print $2}'
```

8618b8fe-93a9-488c-a901-0df30898c82e

or

root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# block info | grep sdb2
/dev/sdb2: UUID="8618b8fe-93a9-488c-a901-0df30898c82e" NAME="EXT_JOURNAL" VERSION="1.0" TYPE="ext4"

I want to then replace the word hotdog with the random uuid, and keep the semi-colons. Keep in mind that the uuid will change each time I format that partition.